# execute dbms_connection_pool.start_pool(); not able to execute

Tags: oracle, database-connection

I am not able to execute this command, Even I am in system user. I tried with both that is in command prompt even in Oracle SQL developer tool.
When i am executing the below command in System user

```
execute dbms_connection_pool.start_pool();
```

I am getting error as

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
EXECUTE DBMS_CONNECTION_POOL.START_POOL()
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_CONNECTION_POOL.START_POOL' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

For your information I am user oracle express 12c

Comment: There is no Oracle Express 12c

Answer (score 0):

The database resident connection pool (`DRCP`) reduces the resource requirements of applications that currently don't support connection pooling, either because it is not supported by the application infrastructure, or it has not been implemented. `DRCP` is only supported for database connections using the `OCI` driver. The pool is managed using the `dbms_connection_pool` package. And the operation is started by `start_pool` procedure.

You can call this procedure in these two ways :

```
SQL> exec dbms_connection_pool.start_pool( pool_name => 'my_connection_pool');
```

*or*

```
SQL> exec dbms_connection_pool.start_pool;
```

***but not like in the below way :***

```
SQL> exec dbms_connection_pool.start_pool();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

```
conn / as sysdba
```

and

```
exec dbms_connection_pool.start_pool;
```

worked for me

and

```
SELECT connection_pool, maxsize
FROM dba_cpool_info;
```

to get the info about pool